# What is the probability that of all fish caught, none are from the same species?

Tags: probability

There are k species of fish known to be present in a body of water. A marine biologist studying the marine life in the water catches n fish in a net with the aim of catching fish from as many species as possible. What is the probability that of all fish caught, none are from the same species?

Comment: You need to know something about the relative populations of the species before you can answer this.

Comment: Thanks paul but i'm just look for a good way to approach this question or some form of suitable formula.

Comment: If there are $k$ species and $n>k$, then at least two must be from the same species by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).